# Avoiding long "bare" branches in BST and balancing

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

So I'm experimenting a little bit with binary search trees and need some hints here.

What I want to implement is a self-balancing BST, but not the usual one. The BST I'm looking for should balance itself ONLY when a long "bare" branch occurs. See the example below for better understading of what I mean by it.

```
         add(6,5,7,1,2,3,4);

          Result BST                        Balanced 
        (before balance)       
               6                              6
            5     7        balance       3         7
         1                  -->       1     4
           2                            2     5
             3
                4         


     x=5
    (long bare branch of length x occurs (5,1,2,3,4)) 
    Balancing starts only when a long bare branch occurs in the BST!
    In this case, after add(4);
```

Long bare branch: Sequence of x nodes that have one child at most, where x is a given constant (in example, it's 5).

Thus once I add(4) to the example BST, a long bare branch occurs and only then the BST requires a fix. So in a way, it's something like AVL tree, but which starts balancing nodes only when a certain amount of unbalanced nodes pile up.

I had some ideas about possible implementations of this, but I think it'd be super inefficient (I'd have to go through the whole tree after add() or remove() and simply just count consecutive nodes with one or less child.)

Any ideas for a more efficient algorithm for such balancing and bare branch occurence detection?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can have a long sequence of left children, with a single right child in every 4th node, and never invoke any balance operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long "bare" branch detection:

- add(): You only need to walk up x nodes. Since x is a (supposedly small) constant, that's O(1)
- remove(): Look up until you find a node with two children or no parent or you reach x steps. If you haven't reached x, look down until you find a none with more than two children (or none). Can't take more than x steps, so O(1) again.